# ExecuteNonQuery returning value of 0 when successfully deleting a record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a slight issue in my C# code in Asp.net when deleting a row from sql server. I am using ExecuteNonQuery to determine which message I render to the page. If ExecuteNonQuery returns a 1 then I display success message. Where I am becoming stuck is I have the same logic for adding a record and updating a record and my code works fine. See below for the code.

```
private void Delete_row(string ImageId)
    {
        string sSQL = "delete FROM dbo.Image_library_UK_temp where Image_id=" + ImageId;
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(app_settings.sql_conn_string_db))
        {
            try
            {

                //delete the row from db
                dbConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, dbConnection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandTimeout = 1024;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 1)
                {

                    messagepanel1.ShowSuccessMessage("The image " + txtImgTitle.Text + "has been deleted from the system.");
                    DisableValidation();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                messagepanel1.ShowErrorMessage("Error: Deletion unsuccessful");
            }

            Session.RemoveAll();
            generateTable(false);

        }
    }
```

Rows affected currently returns 0. This is a simple SQL statement so my sql is hard-coded in C# and I am not using a stored procedure.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: your code is prone to SQL injection which is a very serious security problem !

Comment: did u try to run the query on the sql server directly? does it work?

Comment: This site is for internal purposes otherwise I would agree.

Comment: @nickgowdy - Even if it's an internal site, using prepared statements gives benefits of execution plan re-use, standardised coding practices, type safety, simplified debugging...  I could keep going on, but let's just say there isn't a very good case for not using them.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're executing the command twice.

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The first line will delete the row and return 1, but you're ignoring the return value.
The second line will execute the `DELETE` statement again, but it won't delete anything, because there is no more rows satisfying the given condition; thus, `rowsAffected` will be zero.

Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injections, as was already mentioned in comments. Consider using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that mistake. I will mark this as correct when Stackoverflow lets me :(

Comment: As an aside, if you're using the same code for your create and update points, you need to edit it there as well. Otherwise, your create will insert the sam record twice.